# Change button state if a row in tableView is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableView when a row is selected I would like to show a button on the bottom (outside of the tableView) to be shown (isEnabled = true) when I have no rows selected I want it to be set to disabled (isEnabled = false. How can I handle this the best?

Currently I have this logic but when I try to select multiple rows this gives me issues. Because the first select will enable it and the second will disable it.

Here is the code:

I store a true or false in a var on the top called: var someRowSelected = false

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        selectedCell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)


        if(!someRowSelected){
            self.someRowSelected = true
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
        }else{
            self.someRowSelected = false
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        selectedCell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.darkGray

        if(!someRowSelected){
            self.someRowSelected = true
            nextBtn.isEnabled = true
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
        }else{
            self.someRowSelected = false
            nextBtn.isEnabled = false
            nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }
    }
```

I am curious if someone can help me out.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine however it will work if only one cell is selected, because what you are essentially doing is changing the value of the Bool to true is selected then false if deselected without checking the total number of selected rows.

The easiest way without changing a lot of your code is to add a new variable called

```
var rowsSelected = 0
```

And in your didSelectRow add one to the `rowsSelected += 1`
Then in your if statement check if the value of

```
If rowsSelected is >= 1 { 
//enable and un hide your button
}
```

On the deselectRow do the opposite and subtract 1 from `rowsSelected -= 1` then the If statement `if rowsSelected == 0 { //hide the button and disable it}`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome dude! This is simple and works like a charm. Exactly what i was looking for. Really thank you for this solution. :D

Comment: Do you know how I can retrieve the data from the UITabelCell and put it in a variable so I can send it to my firebase Database?

Comment: I'm glade that I could help...if you can elaborate more I might regarding what your trying to accomplish I will happily assist

Comment: sure what is your github account?

Comment: Sorry I don't have one￼

Comment: how od you want to collab?

Comment: Whatever is your preference, is be at my computer in about an hour...please do let me know so I can offer my assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have made a small change in your code. See if it helps you. Create a variable on the top like `someRowSelected`

```
var indexPAthSelected : NSIndexPath?

if !someRowSelected {
    self.someRowSelected = true
    nextBtn.isEnabled = true
    nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 84.0 / 255, green: 199.0 / 255, blue: 252.0 / 255, alpha: 1)
    indexPAthSelected = indexPath
} else if indexPAthSelected == indexPath {
    self.someRowSelected = false
    nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    nextBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
} else {

}
```

Comment: It does not recognize indexPath. use of unresolved identiefier indexPath